# Object Capture Command Line not working for me

Tags: ios, realitykit, wwdc

I am trying to make this to work but after building the command line app, I kept getting error when running https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_a_photogrammetry_command-line_app

I am using MacBook-Air 2017 and Xcode 13.0 beta 4,

Example error:

```
2021-08-09 15:23:20.035254+0530 HelloPhotogrammetry[6390:70439] Metal API Validation Enabled
2021-08-09 15:23:23.280756+0530 HelloPhotogrammetry[6390:70439] [HelloPhotogrammetry] Error creating session: cantCreateSession("A GPU that is not in low power mode is required. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433409-lowpower")
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

I am new to reality kit

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately only the newer Macs are compatible with the photogrammetry SDK.

It sounds like your Mac won't be as it's an Air from 2017. All M1 Macs are compatible and some of the more recent Intel Macs with boosted graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the minimal requierments at:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10076/  - 2:35

To sum it up, you need one of the following:

- M1 Apple silicon computer
- Intel x86_64 with 4GB AMD Graphics and 16GB Ram.

Either on of the two will work.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple documentation, **Photogrammetry API** supported only mac with following features.

- All Apple Silicon Macs
- Intel Mac's with 4GB AMD and 16GB RAM

So please make sure your mac is supported above conditions to run Photogrammetry API.